# how to run a command before logging to fedora system?

Tags: linux, bash

*emphasized text*I need to run:

```
chmod 777 /tmp
```

before the logging window (user name and password) appears.

The effect can not be kept once I restart the operating system:

> ls -ld /tmp 
>   drwxr-xr-t 2 root root 4096 Feb  5 01:53 /tmp

Every time I have to run it by hand when I log into the system.

How to realize it automatically?

*It is very rare that I can log in to my system successfully at the first time.

Usually,I have to input my user name and password many times before I can log into my system successfully. 

Sometimes I can see my desktop after my input,but it will stay there and something below appears:

the following installation problem was detected while trying to start KDE..writing to the temp directory /tmp failed with the error 'permission denied '...kde unable to start.
I push OK then 'could not start ksmserver,check your installat' appears. Every goes back to the logging window.*

Comment: Modify your startup scripts?

Comment: why would you need this?

Comment: if not,my firefox will fail to open

Comment: What is the permissions on /tmp? What sort of filesystem is /tmp?

Comment: The startup scripts are run before or after I input username and password at the logging window?  How to do it?

Comment: my system is i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux.  I have changed the ownership of /tmp.      $ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root 4096 Feb  5 00:03 /tmp

Comment: The real question is what's changing it back. On my RHEL system, /tmp was set to drwxrwxrwt and I've never had to change it.

Answer (score 2):

The `/tmp` directory on Unix/Linux ***should*** be read/writable to everyone. This is the directory almost all programs will use. The question is what could possibly be changing the permissions on this directory all of the time.

- Is it changed while the system is up and running?
- Does it change only when the system is shutdown?
- Does it get changed at a particular time of the day?

If the permissions of `/tmp` gets changed at boot time, I would go through your `/etc/init.d` scripts and see what's going on. These are almost always shell scripts that get run during both startup and sometimes shutdown.

You can create your own script in `/etc/init.d` which just does a `/bin/ls -ld /tmp`. Then, you can create the links from this *script* to the `/etc/rc3.d` directory. If you start the file name with `Sxx` (where `xx` is a number between `01` and `99`, it will run during start up in the order of the number. if you have the console showing during startup, you can see when this file's permissions are changed. Starting the name with `Kxx` will run that during shutdown. Again, you can try different `xx` to see when it is getting changed.

What you can do is make a `/etc/init.d` script that simply does a `chmod 777 /tmp` and have it run during the startup. (by putting it in the `/etc/rc3.d` directory with a name starting with `Sxx`. However, my concern is that you might set it up correctly, but then have something change the permissions back during startup.

Comment: your method is just  to see when /tmp changes,not to run `chmod 777 /tmp`,right?

Comment: First try to find why `/tmp` is being changed. Nothing should be changing the permission on `/tmp` It should ALWAYS be `0777` and owned by root so no one can delete it. BTW, is `/tmp` a local directory? Maybe it's being mounted? Maybe the mount is incorrect? Check `df -k /tmp`. However, if all else fails, then the only way to change the permission of `/tmp` before anyone logs in is to use a script in `/etc/init.d` (linked into `/etc/rc3.d`) that will do a `chmod 777 /tmp`. That should **not** be done, but what else can you do if all else fails?

Comment: It is changed while I restart my system.   `df -k   /tmp`                  
`Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on`  
`/dev/sda11      96003472 82081728   9114064  91% /tmp`

Comment: I put `/bin/chmod 1777 /tmp`  in `/etc/init.d/` and made a soft link to `/etc/rc3.d`,but there is no effect.

Comment: Did you first try to determine what could be changing the mode of `/tmp`? It's important to know. Otherwise, whatever is doing it could be changing it on you after you've set it in a startup script. Here's something I thought of: Do a `ls -i /tmp` and get the inode of the `/tmp` directory. Next boot, see if it changed. If it did, it means something deleting it and recreating it. Or, it could be a remote drive mount.

Comment: yes,I tried `ls -i /tmp`.It really changes every time I restart. The computer is frozen after I input username and passwd and before all the desktop icons appear.The KDE icon can not appear. At this moment,I ssh to this computer with another computer and `chmod 1777 /tmp`. I use mouse to trigger the error which I describe at the end of my post,then the log in window appears again. This time,I can log in successfully.

Comment: I realize it changes when you restart, but the question is still what is changing it. This might be pointing out a bigger issue - like a tiny rattle you hear in your car when you step on the accelerator. When is that permission changed? Is it changed on shutdown or restart? What process is running that's changing it? That's why I suggest to do a `ls -ld /tmp` as both a startup and shutdown process. You can still do that and have the `chmod 777 /tmp`, but you still need to determine what is not quite right with this system.